# Binding the Value of StringFormat

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, string-formatting

I have a Textbox with a `Value` and a `Unit` bound like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value,StringFormat='{}{0} mm'}" />
```

The Unit `mm` should be also bound to the `ViewModel` Property `Unit`. This can be done via a Multibinding:

```
<TextBox>
   <TextBox.Text>
      <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
         <Binding Path="Value"
            Mode="TwoWay" />
         <Binding Path="Unit"
            Mode="OneWay" />
      </MultiBinding>
   </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

But with this I lose my Two Way Binding and I don't want to edit the Unit aswell. If ths user deletes "8 mm" and enteres an "8" the binding should automatically reevaluate the binding and add the unit as it is done via normal string format binding.

So finally I need something like this:

```
<TextBox>
   <TextBox.Text>
      <Binding Path="Value"
         StringFormat="{Binding Path=ValueUnitStringFormat}" />
   </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

But unfortunally `StringFormat` Property on `BindingBase` is not a `DependencyProperty`.

Anyone got a solution for this?

Comment: should the unit be changeable by the user?

Comment: why don't you use a converter ?

Comment: Dealing with the user just entering "8", you can use BindingBase.FallbackValue for the"mm"

Comment: If the user is not supposed to be able to edit the unit, then just put it into a `TextBlock` and display it after the `TextBox`.

Comment: @blindmeis Unit should not be changed by the user.

Comment: @sheridan This would be the last solution. I want to display the unit inside the textbox.

Comment: why do you think using `MultiBinding` does not support 2 way? you can set 2 way binding with it normally.

Comment: I don't want to use multibinding. The question is: how can I bind "StringFormat" expression?

Comment: so I can be 99.99% sure that you cannot set some Binding for it. it's not a DependencyProperty and Binding is also not a DependencyObject. Simply being stuck.

Comment: You might be looking for MaskedTextBox.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/wpf-maskedtextbox-control/

Comment: *I want to display the unit inside the textbox*... why? If it is not supposed to be editable by the user, then why do you want to put it into an editable control?